# AngularJS - Typeahead with $http and $timeout

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I would like to implement a typeahead in my angular application.

So, when the user fills in the input, I want to wait 1second and verify if the input is the same after 1second, and if it's the same, then I send the request to my server.

I do it by implementing a $http in a $timeout, which works successfully but I want to know if it is a good way.

There is my controller :

```
$scope.getLocation = function (input) {

        var input_tmp = input;

        return $timeout(function () {
            if (input === input_tmp) {

                $scope.query.FilterIdentification = input;

                return $http.get(SERVER_REST.url, $scope.query)
                    .then(function (res) {
                        var addresses = [];

                        angular.forEach(res.data, function (item) {
                            addresses.push(item);
                        });

                        return addresses;
                    });
            }
        }, 1000);

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite an old question, I know - just wanted to point out, that this is now a built-in feature:

See http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

"*typeahead-wait-ms  (Defaults: 0) : Minimal wait time after last character typed before typeahead kicks-in*"

Other than that, I see nothing wrong with your way of doing it.